# I installed a second linux distro wiped it and it removed grub

Tags: grub2

I'm running Ubuntu as my only OS right now. I added elementary OS and decided I didn't like it. I then deleted the partition and added the space back to my main Ubuntu partition. This proceeded to wipe grub. I did the ls command on grub recovery mode found the ext2 partition my computer was running on but insmod came up with a error every single time. The only way I was able to get my machine running again was to install a second copy of ubuntu on a 20gb partition on my same drive and leave that on there. I'm going to be installing windows as a second OS in a day or two here and need the extra ubuntu gone cause its wasting space. I need help finding a way to ensure grub remains function after I delete the extra partition with ubuntu and before I restart my system and it loses track of my main ubuntu. I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you installed elementary, it took ownership of the MBR, meaning it controlled the booting of your system. When you deleted it, the MBR pointed to a non-existing `grub` (/boot/grub/ on the deleted elementary partition) thus the failure to boot. By re-installing another Ubuntu, you had it take over ownership of the MBR (first sector of the drive be it hdd/ssd)..   You make the first Ubuntu you want to keep own the MBR first with a `grub-install` command.

Comment: Note: the question doesn't really apply to your circumstance; but the commands are appropriate to *fix* your issue.  Another user of the site may find a better (closer to your issue) question for you if you wait.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? Generally you need to reinstall grub from your remaining system. Boot-Repair can do that, but you need to boot live installer in same boot mode as your install. Or you may be able to use SuperGrub to boot and then you can reinstall grub from inside your system. Knowing if UEFI or BIOS will determine best way to fix system.